# Cognito Hosted UI, How to get and set access token to browser

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito Hosted UI to login. After logined, i want to store the access token to the browser to make further api request.
I did the following steps

1. Redirect to CognitoUI by calling a Redirect (URL)
   [image]
2. After login successfully, it auto calls the callback url  with the authorization-code
   [image]
3. I intend to get the access token by the authorization code=> successfully
4. I don't know to send the access-token back to browser, because it was called 302 request.

I'm using ASP Net Core and the client is using Jquery

Anyone please help me ?

Comment: Can we use ajax request to call the Cognito UI ?, i tried but it throw error has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I added the header already "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post on the same topic - [Authenticating users in ASP.NET Core MVC using Amazon Cognito](https://coderjony.com/blogs/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using-amazon-cognito?source=stackoverflow).

If you have implemented the **Cognito Authentication** in the similar way with `AddOpenIdConnect` extension method, then you can retrieve the `access_token` with the following code

```cs
string accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
```